# show browser preferences & Page Setup using javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to use javascript to activate the preferences dialog, so that a user can change a proxy address if they need to & also be able to click on an anchor link and have the Page Setup Dialog open, so that they can choose the page orientation for printing.

The reason for this, is becuase I am trying to use mozilla Prism to deploy a web application, but I have hidden the Navigation Bar & Status Bar(which contains the Prism's button for setting these preferences). I want Prism to be just a frame.

I have not posted in Prism discussion forums, becuase maybe there is standard javascript way of opening up these dialogs, can you(anyone) share how if it is possible. A firefox workaround will be enough, since prism is based on Firefox. Thanks.